# Order of columns in a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

There's a table with 50 columns that someone created a few years ago and it's a huge table.

I am adding some new functionality to the application and I added 3 more tables.
Now because I want to relate these new tables, I added relation_id's to the original table.

Of course all these relation_id columns  appear at the end when you check it from a database tool which has a GUI.

I would like to see these new relation ID's next to the very first ID column of the first table in my database designer, right after it because I am a neat person.

Please don't tell me that column order is something unnecessary and it doesn't do any good to move them to the front.

For example, I didn't see an example of a table creation like this, in this order.

`CREATE TABLE info(
city_id integer,
blood_type varchar(10),
dateupdated date,
last_name varchar(40),
country_id integer,
email_address varchar(250),
datecreated date,
first_name varchar(40),
id integer,
mid_name varchar(40),
gender char(1)
soc_security_number integer
)`

Why does no one create tables like this? This is a very trivial table but this type of ordering makes it weak in readibility when designing a database. Because we are humans, we want to group columns logically.

After years, the logical groups in your initial table might get out of order too.

Now please look at this command in a Firebird database:
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER field_name POSITION new_position

As you can see they don't reorganize or recreate a table.
It just returns the columns in that specified order.
The column order is kept in internal tables.
This can give PostgreSQL developers a clue how to do this in a simple way too.

Still, is there a way to do this without recreating the table that I am missing?

Regards

Comment: Don't make the mistake to follow the accepted answer in the duplicate question. It will lead to data corruption. You cannot change the column order. A relational database is no spreadsheet. What you want is part of the presentation layer of an application.

Comment: Okay. It's actually very impractical for me to recreate the table I have. As you say, a better and simpler approach would be changing the table view at the presentation layer. And Firebird database already demonstrate that it can be done like this.

Comment: Create a view that is basically just a copy of your table, but using the column order you like. And only use this view to get access to the data.